# Perform segue after notification access has been granted

Tags: swift, appdelegate, remote-notifications

I would like to know how to perform a modal segue after the remote notification access has been granted from the dialog box. I have set up my remote notification in the app delegate.

```
func registerANSForApplication(_ application: UIApplication,withBlock block: @escaping (_ granted:Bool) -> (Void)){
    InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
        } else if let result = result {
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
            AppDelegate.isToken = result.token
        }
    }
    let current  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let options : UNAuthorizationOptions = [.sound, .badge, .alert]

    current.requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, error) in
        guard granted else{
            return
        }
        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        }else{
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
            current.delegate = self
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then, in my view controller, I have this code:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! 
appDelegate.registerANSForApplication(UIApplication.shared) { (granted) -> (Void) in
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MembershipVC", sender: nil)
}
```

The problem is whether the user allows or denies the access to notification, the segue is not executed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: start by adding some print there and see if it gets called, or just add a breakpoint

Comment: It does not get called...

Comment: What is `registerANSForApplication`? And you should at least handle the `granted` parameter.

Comment: When I handle this parameter like if granted{ perform segue } it does not do anything.

Comment: Of course it doesn’t do anything because you don’t call the completion ***block***.

Comment: So please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `block` parameter

Replace

```
current.requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, error) in
    guard granted else{
        return
    }
    if error != nil{
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    }else{
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        current.delegate = self
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
current.requestAuthorization(options: options) { (granted, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        block(false)
    } else {
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        current.delegate = self
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            block(granted)
        }
    }

}
```